DynamoDB Local features coverage sheet
I can't seem to find detailed AWS documentation about AWS DynamoDB Local, and it would come in handy because we have a large integration test suite that uses it. For example, I learned the hard way that operations related with table exports (e.g. ExportTableToPointInTime, DescribeExport, ListExports) are not supported.
Executing (against latest version of docker image):
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:8000 dynamodb describe-export --export-arn "{MyDDBExportARN}"
Results in:
An error occurred (UnknownOperationException) when calling the DescribeExport operation: An unknown operation was requested.
